# How to make tables go horizontal instead of up to down?

Tags: java

```
 public class lab7for {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     
         System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
         int num = in.nextInt();
         System.out.println("\nInput number of terms: ");
         int terms = in.nextInt();
     
         System.out.println("\n");
     
         for (int i = 1; i <= terms; i++) {
             int product = num * i;
             System.out.println(num + " x " + i + " = " + product);
         }
         System.out.printf("\n");

         for (int i2 = 1; i2 <= terms; i2++) {
             int num2 = num +1;
             int product2 = num2 * i2;
             System.out.println(num2 + " x " + i2 + " = " + product2);
         }
         System.out.printf("\n");
     
         for (int i3 = 1; i3 <= terms; i3++) {
             int num3 = num + 2;
             int product3 = num3 * i3;
             System.out.println(num3 + " x " + i3 + " = " + product3);
         }
         System.out.printf("\n");
     
         for (int i4 = 1; i4 <= terms; i4++) {
             int num4 = num + 3;
             int product4 = num4 * i4;
             System.out.println(num4 + " x " + i4 + " = " + product4);
         }
         System.out.printf("\n");
     }

 }
```

So my code does this.
[multiplication tables go up to down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20BVG.png)

How can I make it so that the 7x7, 8x8, 9x9, and 10x10 tables are beside each other?
Like this:
[horizontal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbhMs.png)
Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, There's no simple way to print horizontally in Java.
However, in this case we can do this with a workaround

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    int num = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("\nInput number of terms: ");
    int terms = in.nextInt();
    int currentNumber = 0;
    System.out.println("\n");

    for (int i = 1; i <= terms; i++) {
        currentNumber = num;
        for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
            int product = currentNumber * i;
            System.out.print(currentNumber + " x " + i + " = " + product);
            System.out.print("\t");
            currentNumber++;
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```